# How do I Unignore a file in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I ignored a file in TortoiseSVN by mistake. How do I reverse this and add the file to my repository?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Just edit the svn:ignore property (in the subversion tab of the directory properties).
(If you ignored a subfolder, select the property tab of it's parent folder)

Comment: Might be worth to take a look in svn:globalignore property, too

Comment: Also look at the same tab in subfolders if you can't find anything at root level

Answer (score 19):

If you right click on the directory containing the file and select SVN Properties, you should see an svn:ignore property with a list of ignored files. Simply edit that list and remove the rule ignoring your file.

Comment: The menu structure for me was `right click on folder`->TortoiseSVN->Properties. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 18):

["Ignoring Files And Directories"](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html) from the Tortoise SVN documentation  states:

> If you want to remove one or more items from the ignore list, **right click** on those items and select **`TortoiseSVN`** → **`Remove from Ignore List`** You can also access a folder's `svn:ignore` property directly. That allows you to specify more general patterns using filename globbing, described in the section below. Read [the section called “Project Settings”](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) for more information on setting properties directly. Please be aware that each ignore pattern has to be placed on a separate line. Separating them by spaces does not work.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the solution was to use **"Update to Revision"**.

My ignored files had been set as ignored automatically when I did a checkout but had not put a checkmark by the files.

When I did Update to Revision, I verified that the files were to be included by going to "Chose Items..."

I was not able to find anything in the properties menu that listed ignored files (a la Gabriel's suggestion).  In fact, the properties were empty.

Comment: That was my case (forgot checkmark at checkout) and "update to revision" worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was another problem: the [global ignore list](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-main) in tortoise Settings, General.

Tortoise ships by default with .so files in the ignore list and we store these in source control (yes I know this is far from ideal). Removing them from the list sorted it out for me.

Answer (score -2):

I usually just add the ignored file with Tortoise and don't bother to remove the entry from the ignore list. so far I had no negative side effect...

Comment: When the file is ignored, Add no longer shows up as an option in the TortoiseSVN menu

Comment: that is not what I experience. I checked the checkbox for the "add" command in the tortoise svn settings under context menu. this way the "add" command always appears directly in the explorer context menu. maybe this makes a difference?

Comment: I've made that change as well and I don't see it in the context menu for ignored directories.