# Delete all files being ignored within a Subversion checkout

Tags: svn, file-management, svnignore

How can I delete all files that are being ignored within a Subversion checkout?  Effectively to bring it back to the equivalent of a pristine checkout.

Comment: What platform are you on? In Linux, there may be some crazy way of comparing a svn output and a `ls` output and delete those files that don't overlap or something. In Windows, if you can use TortoiseSVN, you may be able to work in the GUI with the "ignored" icons - which is not 100% reliable though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this script when I want to clean out a working copy.  It removes all unknown and ignored files.

```
svn status --no-ignore | awk '$1=="?"||$1=="I" { print $2 }' | xargs -i rm -rf {}
```

Answer (score 3):

If **TortoiseSVN**, you can `Check for modifications`, `Show ignored files`, right click and delete.

Answer (score 1):

[karoberts' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555135/delete-all-files-being-ignored-within-a-subversion-checkout/3555175#3555175) doesn't work on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard). Neither does [another command I found on a blog](http://blog.johnjosephbachir.org/2006/11/10/one-liner-for-deleting-all-unknown-files-from-an-svn-working-copy/)

I get

> xargs: illegal option -- i

and

> xargs: illegal option -- d

respectively.

This works on Mac (adapted from karoberts'):

```
svn status | awk '$1=="?"||$1=="I" { print $2 }' | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first reverse the ignore state of those files (ref [How do I Unignore a file in TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326649/how-do-i-unignore-a-file-in-tortoisesvn) for details) and then you can delete and commit back the changes from your workspace methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it.

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep "^[\?I]" | sed 's%^........%%' | xargs -d "\\n" rm -rv
```