# How to commit jnilibs to svn

Tags: svn

I have got a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader` I found that cause of the problem. Now In my source code file called "example.so" file is present under arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a. I want to commit that file to svn. But it is not showing up for commit. So kindly anybody help me with this.

I want to commit that file to svn...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Unignore a file in TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326649/how-do-i-unignore-a-file-in-tortoisesvn)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`svn add`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/add/) the file to add it your working copy and make Subversion track this file. Then [`svn commit`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/commit/) this change.

Note that it is possible that your [`svn:ignore` pattern](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/props/special/ignore/) makes Subversion ignore this file.